# Selecting images except those which are found in certain div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
lazyLoad: function () {
        $("img").unveil(200);
}
```

But I need to

> $("img").unveil(200);

did not act on all the images. 
I need to have taken all the pictures, except for those that are in these div's:

```
 1) <div class="l-column l-column_1"></div>
 2) <div class="counters"></div>
 3) <footer class="footer"></footer>
```

I guess you need correctly to make selector using ": not"?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("img:not(.l-column, .counters, .footer)")
```